# backbone js difference between getters vs direct access of model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

what is the advantage/ reason for backbone-js to use the syntax

```
//using a Model instance called model

model.get('attribute')
```

and not

```
model.attribute
```

Im just starting to use backbone and I always ind myself trying to access the attributes directly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the source code, the `get` function just calls to `this.attributes[name]`.

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-31

The benefit, though, is at least two-fold:

1) a consistent API that reduces the amount of code you are writing

2) the ability to override the `get` method and provide more complex access control

For example, there are several plugins for backbone that override how models work in order to provide nested model capabilities. it's very easy for them to allow you to write a get method like this:

`model.get("submodel.attr")`

and have that parse out the `attr` of the `submodel` sub-model. Without the get method, it would be more difficult to make this consistent with the API.

The underlying benefit from this is encapsulation, though. Until JavaScript provides true get/set properties that let us write code for getters and setters, we'll be stuck with work-around methods like Backbone's `get` and `set`.

Comment: Can You please clarify how `user.get('name')` vs `user.name` reduces the amount of code?

Comment: I guess he means you use `user.get('name')` instead of `user.attributes['name']` which is longer. For accessing nested models, however, I would use this syntax: `user.attributes.name.first`

Answer (score 2):

Well .. for starters, `model.attribute` is absolutely NOT correct. `model.set()` is required in order to get `change` events to fire. You're very likely to forget this if you get in the habit of using `model.attributes[attribute]` instead of `model.get(attribute)`